# Security Flaws?

Tags: php, security

What are the repercussions of using this code?

```
<?php
if(file_exists("pages/" . $_GET["page"] . ".php")){
    include("pages/" . $_GET["page"] . ".php");
    } else{
        include("pages/home.php");
        }
?>
```

I've made it so that you cannot load anything without a ".php" extension, so I'm thinking it's pretty safe to use. If you use:

```
website.com/index.php?page=../index
```

In the url it will create an infinite loop. You can't load an external URL as far as I know.

Example:

```
website.com/index.php?page=anothersite.com/virus
```

But I'm not really sure, any suggestions? Or is this alright to use?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php

Comment: You should probably look at Apache's [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) instead (assuming you're using Apache).

Comment: @Matt Browne, what if he doesn't use Apache? There are some other Web Servers available which are much better than Apache.

Comment: I am using apache though @RomanNewaza

Comment: @RomanNewaza That's why I said "assuming you're using Apache" - a tentative assumption I made because it's so common in the PHP world.

Comment: But the "mod_rewrite" is total greek to me... I know I have to update my HTACCESS file but, I'm not that skilled yet haha @MattBrowne

Comment: It may be better to read about the "Front Controller" pattern or use an open-source PHP framework to get the idea of how you can route everything through a single index.php file with search engine-friendly URLs. Sorry I don't have a specific link handy (other than for PHP frameworks which are too numerous to list.)

Comment: Then you could go back to the Apache manual to learn the details.

Comment: @Matt Browne, it is not common anymore.

Comment: @RomanNewaza Almost every shared web host runs on Apache, and there are still tons of websites running on shared hosting. I'm sure it's not as common with virtual/dedicated hosts as it used to be...

Comment: @MattBrowne, we stopped using it about 5 years ago as it is too slow for us. You can search google for surveys for HTTPD usage. Yea, it is still common, but it doesn't mean it is good - the same story with PHP. The language  is ugly, but wide used ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out by [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms), depending on the PHP version, `file_exists` and `include` may [not be safe when handling NULL bytes](http://php.net/security.filesystem.nullbytes). Only [since PHP version 5.4.3, filesystem functions are said to be NULL byte safe](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60985).

So you should validate the value before using it, e.g., by using a white list of allowed values:

```
$allowedPages = array(/* … */);
if (in_array($_GET["page"], $allowedPages)) {
    // allowed
}
```

You can also expand this white list to any existing file below the document root directory:

```
if (strpos($_GET["page"], "\0") !== false) {
    // NULL byte detected
}
$path = realpath("pages/" . $_GET["page"] . ".php");
$base = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . "/";
if ($path !== false && substr($path, 0, strlen($base)) === $base) {
    // allowed
}
```

However, this still may be used to bypass other access control measures like HTTP authorization based on the location.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `../../` pattern combined with a null byte can cause the path to "escape" its enclosure.

```
"../../../etc/passwd\0.php"
```

There are two things you can do about it:

1. Use a white list of possible values you're willing to accept.
2. Sanitize the path first, e.g.

   ```
   $path = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '');
   // now use $path as you would
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's insecure to include page according to URL parameters, which canbe easily messed up by users, you'd better avoid that.

Second, if you want to avoid including external url, you may need to configure php.ini according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

If you're not still into configure php.ini, your can trim the "http://", "https://" strings in  $_GET['page'] at first, which is a good behavior, and make a **.htaccess** file to redirect unexist page request to home.php, you also have to make sure mod_rewrite is on your server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ home.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this, as you pointed out can result in an infinite loopy hat will cause php to crash.

Php crashing can result in a lot of bad things. Eg you can upload temporary files that won't be removed. This could ultimately lead to huge leaks and attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I will result into a serious vulnerability known as Local file inclusion, the GET parameters are not filtered better filter it as mentioned by jack or simply use php [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function which is a bit simple.